# Mission mandatory for virtualsticks?

Tags: dji-sdk

is that mandatory to upload a mission to use virtualsticks??? I'm having that problem

when I try to use it without to upload a mission it never change to joystick mode

anyone with this ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking if uploading a mission IS required in order to use Virtual Joysticks, the answer is no.  All flight modes are unique and separate and do not rely on one another.  In fact if you start Virtual Joystick and try to start a mission upload I expect it will either error (something about flight mode) or just cancel the one mode and prepare for the new mode.